# enable azure search synonyms

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, synonym, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm trying to enable a synonym map to some fields using the following code:

```
public ActionResult ConfigFieldToUseSynonyn()
        {
            string searchServiceName = "xxx";
            string apiKey = "123123123123123123123123123";

            SearchServiceClient serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(apiKey));
            var index = serviceClient.Indexes.Get("produtos");

            index.Fields[2].SynonymMaps = new string[] { "marca-synonymmap" };
            index.Fields[7].SynonymMaps = new string[] { "marca-synonymmap" };

            serviceClient.Indexes.CreateOrUpdate(index, accessCondition: AccessCondition.IfNotChanged(index));

            return Content("OK");
        }
```

and the definition using the following code:

```
public ActionResult Synonym()
        {
            string searchServiceName = "xxx";
            string apiKey = "123123123123123123123123123";

            SearchServiceClient serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(apiKey));
            var indexClient = serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient("produtos");

            var synonymMap = new SynonymMap()
            {
                Name = "marca-synonymmap",
                Format = "solr",
                Synonyms = @"
                 dolve, douve => dove\n
                "
            };

            serviceClient.SynonymMaps.CreateOrUpdate(synonymMap);

            return Content("OK");
        }
```

when I'm trying to find products using "dolve" it's not mapping to "dove". What am I missing?

PS: those fields are searchable and string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of the synonymmap, the '@' marks the string content as a verbatim literal and the rule becomes dolve, douve => dove\n, with the "\n" in the end. This synonym rule rewrites the query 'dolve' to 'dove\n'. Synonyms will work as expected if you remove the '@' prefix or remove the new line '\n' in the synonym definition.

Nate